# How can you perform form validation at form level (not at field level)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I know you can use a FormTextField to validate user input at the field level, but say you have First Name and Last Name as fields, and you would like to make sure that at least one of them is filled in.

How can you achieve that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll share what I did in this scenario. I use `TextEditingController` for these two fields. And after `Form` is validated I also check these two fields from controllers and if it matches to the condition then I submit values.If it does not, I show an alert dialog.